# Index issue of ngFor when used with Pagination

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using pagination and ngFor along with searchPipe. The problem is with index of ngFor. My paginator shows 10 items per page, but problem is when I go to second page index of ngFor returns to the 0. So I can only iterate from 0-10 elements basically for each page from my data set. Any help is appreciated.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of testdata | customStoreFilter:searchRetail | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p };let i = index"
          [ngClass]="eachmodel[i] ? 'active': ''" id="row{{i}}">
<td>
            <textarea  [(ngModel)]='remarks[i]'
              (change)="isRemarksModelChanged($event.target.value,i,item)"></textarea>
          </td>
</tr>
```

So let i = index part is not working correctly. Lets say I have 50 items in my testdata. It should iterate from 0 to 50, instead it goes from 0 to 10th element in each page since itemsPerPage is 10. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: Please complete for [mcve]

Comment: it only shows data in remarks array from 0 to 10. But let s say I have 50 data in testdata.Then it should show the data in remarks from 0 to 50. This is the problem

Answer (score 3):

I am writing for angular 4+, refering [ngx-pagination][1],

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page };index as i">
    <span *ngIf="page==1">{{(i+1)}}{{item}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="page>1">{{((page-1)*10)+(i+1)}}{{ item }}</span>
  </li>
    </ul>

    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page =$event">
</pagination-controls>
```

```
 export class AppComponent {
  page:number = 1;
  collection = [];
  constructor() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      this.collection.push(`item ${i}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood your question correctly this what you want.

```
<tr
  *ngFor="let item of testdata | customStoreFilter:searchRetail | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p };index as i"
  [ngClass]="eachmodel[i] ? 'active': ''" id="row{{i}}">
  <td>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]='remarks[i]' (change)="isRemarksModelChanged($event.target.value,i,item)"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Try the above one if you didn't understand let me know i will edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but problem is still same. Let s say I have 50 objects in my testdata and then I will have 5 pages because itemsPerPage is 10. But my problem is let i=index. For example; when I click to the second page, the i which is index should be 11-20, but for every page the "i" is only from 0 to 10. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: every page the "i" is only from 0 to 10. it's true you can use pageIndex and pageSize to calculator index.

Answer (score 0):

> Exactly I don't know where you want to show List of items per page but have you added pagination control like below:

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>.
```

So, try it with simple UL/Li first

Comment: Its not about pagination. The problem is let i = index. Let s say I have 50 object in testdata. Then I will have 5 pages. Then lets say I open the second page. The i which is index should be 11 but it is 1 again. So for everypage index is from 0-10

Answer (score 0):

write a method in your component.ts file:

```
getIndex(i: number) {
let pageCorrection: number;
let indexPerPage = 10;
if (this.p === 1) {
  pageCorrection = 0;
} else {
  pageCorrection = (this.p - 1) * indexPerPage;
}
return i + 1 + pageCorrection;
```

}

use it in your component.html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of testdata | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p };let i = index">
<span *ngIf="page>=1">{{getIndex(i)}}</span> 
</div>
```